# Running into segmentation fault when creating an array of a struct

Tags: c++, c, syntax, segmentation-fault

For whatever reason, I cant figure out why I'm running into a segmentation fault.
I've created an array of type 'Card' that should hold 5 cards. Then in make hand I want to add a suit and face to each card in that array.

I think the problem is either occurring with the type of data (Constant or non-constant??)
With something passing the array and accessing it in the new function
OR 
with allocating the memory properly.

Please help!! 
Thank you.

**Here is my code to create a user's "hand"
This is where the segmentation fault is happening**

```
// Make the user's hand here
void makeHand(const Card * deck, Card * cardArray[5]){
    // loop through Deck
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%5s of %-8s%s", deck[i].face, deck[i].suit,
               (i + 1) % 4 ? "  " : "\n");

        cardArray[i]->face = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
        strcpy(cardArray[i]->face, deck[i].face);

        cardArray[i]->suit = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
        strcpy(cardArray[i]->suit, deck[i].suit);
    }
}
```

Here is my main function:

```
int main(void){
   Card deck[CARDS]; // define array of Cards

   // initialize array of pointers
   const char *face[] = { "Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
      "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
      "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

   // initialize array of pointers
   const char *suit[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

   srand(time(NULL)); // randomize

   fillDeck(deck, face, suit); // load the deck with Cards
   shuffle(deck); // put Cards in random order
   deal(deck); // deal all 52 Cards

   // Make an array that holds 5 cards, initialize to 0
   Card cardArray[5];
   makeHand(deck, cardArray);

   //twoPair(cardArray);
}
```

General Definitions:

```
#define CARDS 52
#define FACES 13

// card structure definition                  
struct card {                                 
    const char *face; // define pointer face
    const char *suit; // define pointer suit
}; 

typedef struct card Card; // new type name for struct card   

// prototypes
void fillDeck(Card * wDeck, const char * wFace[],
   const char * wSuit[]);
void shuffle(Card * wDeck);
void deal(const Card * wDeck);

// Make a 5 card hand and return it
// should return an array of 5 cards
void makeHand(const Card * deck, Card * cardArray[5]);

// Definitions to check for each condition
void twoPair(Card *cardArray[5]);
```

Comment: `makeHand(Card*, Card* array[])` has 2 different parameter types but you pass the same type (an array of Card) in both. One has to be wrong!

Comment: Are you beholded to all of these c-strings, pointers, arrays, and malloc calls (perhaps this is a school assignment?), or can we convert you to the church of `std::` with its `std::string`, `std::vector`, and no need to manually manage memory?

Comment: What is this `malloc` stuff doing in a C++ program?  In C++, there is `std::string`.

Comment: You should see an error message for the line `makeHand(deck, cardArray);` .  If not then adjust your compiler settings,  as it causes you to waste a lot of time by trying to run an erroneous program

Answer (score 0):

I believe you problem lies in your understanding of pointers.

Essentially, marking a variable with `*` and making it an "array" with `[]` do very very similar things.  They BOTH make a pointer, but with the `[]` operator, you are specifying to the system the length of the array.  The variable is holding the memory address of a point in memory, and an array, before you dereference it, is holding the memory address of a point in memory.  your function:

```
void makeHand(const Card * deck, Card * cardArray[5]){
    // loop through Deck
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%5s of %-8s%s", deck[i].face, deck[i].suit,
               (i + 1) % 4 ? "  " : "\n");

        cardArray[i]->face = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
        strcpy(cardArray[i]->face, deck[i].face);

        cardArray[i]->suit = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
        strcpy(cardArray[i]->suit, deck[i].suit);
    }
}
```

This function takes in a pointer(array) of type `Card` called `deck`, and a pointer(array) of an array of type `Card` called `cardArray`.  Then you call this function like:

makeHand(deck, cardArray);

deck is the correct type, it is a pointer of type `Card`.  However, `cardArray` is only an array, not a pointer to an array.  I'm not sure exactly the functionality you are trying to achieve, but changing makeHand to look like:

```
void makeHand(Card* deck, Card* cardArray) {}
```

should suit your needs.

CLARIFICATION: a pointer is not the same exact thing as an array, I just think it's a useful comparison in understanding the difference between the two.

```
Card* deck;
```

and

```
Card deck[];
```

will do the same thing in memory

Comment: Totally forgot that the name of an array is also a pointer to that array. That fixed it. Thank you!!

Comment: @MackBodie Not quite. It is in a parameter list because you can only pass arrays by reference, but in general arrays are not pointers but can decay to pointers. It's a small difference until it matters, and then it can really mess the program up if you get it wrong.

Comment: True, use my analogy as a general way of thinking, not a strict rule.  a pointer != array, but `Card* deck;` and `Card deck[];` will do the same thing in memory.
@MackBodie mind marking an answer?

Comment: The explanation in first paragraph and the clarification are completely wrong, but the code suggestion is good

Comment: `Card deck[];` is not even allowed in Standard C  or Standard C++ , for a start  (at block or file scope).  Also, in a function parameter list, the length is ignored, and it is a pointer and not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
void makeHand(const Card * deck, Card *cardArray){
    // loop through Deck
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%5s of %-8s%s", deck[i].face, deck[i].suit,
               (i + 1) % 4 ? "  " : "\n");

        cardArray[i].face = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
        strcpy(cardArray[i].face, deck[i].face);

        cardArray[i].suit = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);
        strcpy(cardArray[i].suit, deck[i].suit);
    }
}
```

You probably want to use `cardArray[5];` defined in `main`? For now, you take the array, use it's elements as pointers (they are not pointing to anywhere valid) and try to find the Card structures there (and write to that non-existing "faces" and "suits".

Comment: The `* 25` is suspicious,  to claim the code is "correct" I think it would be good to do something to verify you are not causing a buffer overflow here

Comment: It's usually MAX_LEN constant which is used for both ```malloc()``` and ```const char face[FACES][MAX_LEN]={"Ace"...``` so even if you forget and assign a foreign name like ```"РубашкаКлассическаяАтласная"```, compiler will not allow to overflow the buffer. But passing the LongestName parameter to a function is even better. But I agree, the code could be better (I don't however want to complicate understanding by going too far from the original code).